# How can I "pass a value" into a MYSQL subquery?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, distinct

I need to pass the OD.ID from the parent query's current record to the subquery. I have no idea how to do this, or even if it's possible to do.

The value of OD.ID (line 4 below) will be a unique number for each row in the parent query, and I need to limit the subquery to only records in the OD table that have that ID (attempted on line 10 below). The goal is for the query on line 10 to return a value representing the number of distinct days a person with the given ID has placed an order. The OD database contains a record for each individual item purchased for every order and has columns for purchase day and ID of the purchaser, among other columns. Is it possible to do this?

```
public static function getAthleteReportByDates($start_date, $end_date){
    return Database::runQuery(
        "SELECT 
        OD.ID,
        IF(ISNULL(A.FuelID)=1, 'No Fuel ID', A.FuelID) AS FuelID,
        IF(ISNULL(CONCAT(FirstName, ' ', LastName))=1, 'N/A', CONCAT(FirstName, ' ', LastName)) As Name,
        IF(ISNULL(A.Gender)=1, 'N/A', A.Gender) AS 'Gender',
        IF(ISNULL(S.Name)=1, 'N/A', S.Name) As Sport,
        SUM(F.Price) As Total,
        SUM(F.Price) / (Select Count(Distinct OD.Day, OD.ID) From OrderDetail OD Where (OD.Day Between :start_date And :end_date AND OD.ID = [Pass down value of current parent record's OD.ID here])) AS Average                              
        From OrderDetail OD
        LEFT JOIN Food F
        ON OD.FoodID = F.ID
        LEFT JOIN Athlete A
        ON A.ID = OD.ID
        LEFT JOIN PlaysFor PR
        ON PR.ID = OD.ID
        LEFT JOIN Sports S
        ON PR.SPORT_ID = S.ID
        Where Day Between :start_date And :end_date
        Group By OD.ID, Sport", 
        array(
            'start_date' => $start_date,
            'end_date'=> $end_date
        ));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called a 'correlated subquery'.  You just need to use a different alias in the subquery so you can refer to OD.ID and it knows you mean the outer one:

```
(Select Count(Distinct OD2.Day) From OrderDetail OD2 Where OD2.Day Between :start_date And :end_date AND OD2.ID = OD.ID)
```

Comment: Please try to find dupe targets instead of answering questions that are likely to be duplicates after more than a decade of feverish Q&A with literally millions of contributions.  [The fundamental goal of closing duplicate questions is to help people find the right answer by getting all of those answers in one place.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates#:~:text=The%20fundamental%20goal%20of%20closing%20duplicate%20questions%20is%20to%20help%20people%20find%20the%20right%20answer%20by%20getting%20all%20of%20those%20answers%20in%20one%20place.)

Comment: @mickmackusa I did look; the linked duplicate is IMO not close enough to this question, where both the outer query and the subquery are grouped so a join approach is not helpful, and it might not be clear that the alternate correlated query in the accepted answer was on point (though didn't explicitly call out the need for different aliases)

Comment: The questions don't need to match, the resolving advice needs to be appropriate.   This is the mission of unique "signpost" duplicates -- they represent different scenarios where the same resolving advice can be applied.

Comment: @mickmackusa I disagree where it seems likely the connection between the question and the resolving advice will not be perceptible due to the different focus of the question.  But even so, the resolving advice of the other question was to left join instead of selecting a subquery, and that does not resolve *this* question.

Comment: I have tried to see your perspective and I've asked for an extra set of eyes from the SOCVR chat room and I am still convinced that the dupe target is very much suitable in its advice.  Your answer focuses purely (and correctly) on the subquery in the select clause. The dupe gives the same appropriate guidance to use appropriate aliases to dictate the logic.